# Write to Firebase Firestore outside Android Studio App

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an app for Android using Android Studio and currently I can only write to my Firestore database using the mobile app. However, I want to write to it from outside the app, since I want an administrator to write data to an specific collection without having to use the mobile app.

What are the steps to do so? I've searching for this information but I could not find anything. My idea is to write the program the administrator is going to use in Java, since the Android App is in Java, so the administrator can write the data to the collection as a Java object, and the users of the app can cast the retrieved information using the exact Java object.

So, my best guess is to create a Gradle project with Java, containing that data model, and use my Firestore credentials from that independent project to upload the data, but I don't know how to do so beyond creating the Gradle project with `gradle init`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing was using Java REST API. Two awesome tutorials:

1. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_miu0ihe1k)
2. [And here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScsID2yPB8k)

Comment: These videos are very helpful, indeed. I couldn't find something else to help me in this situation - to connect to Firestore from a simple java program.